# How do you control the number of images to download?

Tags: ios, macos, nsurlsession, flickr, urlsession

How do you *control the number of images* per download request, where each additional download continues where the previous ends?

Example: downloading 30 images at a time; the second batch to lazy download as the user scrolls the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really download multiple images in one request, unless you have some very unusual server infrastructure that does automatic tiling or something.

Most of the time, I would recommend using one of the many open source image/collection view subclasses that provide this sort of functionality for you.  There's typically no need to reinvent the wheel.

That said, if you really want to do it yourself, you would start a task for every image on the first couple of screens, then start new tasks in a scroll event handler based on the scroll speed and expected stop point.  And if a view scrolls off the far side of the screen before you get a `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler` call for its fetch task, you might cancel the fetch.